# Kubernetes master cluster becomes unresponsive when 2 out of 3 master is down,

Tags: kubernetes

We are trying to create k8s cluster environment that spans across 2 data center, We have only 7 BM servers.
We choose to have 2 Master and 2 worker nodes in data center1, In a sunny day scenario this works

But in case of a disaster at data center1, the single master in data center2 becomes unresponsive and does not start any pod in the worker node in data center2 worker nodes and our application service becomes unavailable. Is there a solution to recover this master node back to the service other than bringing back the other two master online.

We set up the clusters using kubeadm  Stacked control plane approach

```
#sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT" --upload-certs
```

Add two more Master to to the cluster using the below command

```
#sudo kubeadm join 192.168.0.200:6443 --token 9vr73a.a8uxyaju799qwdjv --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash
```

When 2 Masters are down  the API server on the third stop listening and the kubectl also stops works,

We tried restarting the available master , but it did not start listening and we were unable to do any actions on the available master. Is there any way to bring back this master into service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not strictly an answer how specifically to solve your problem, but I hope it will somewhat help you anyway.

#### Examplanation

I suppose you are using stacked masters = etcd members and control plane nodes are co-located.

Kubernetes control plane itself is able to run only with 1/3 nodes online. But an etcd cluster needs a majority of nodes, a quorum, to agree on updates to the cluster state.

Etcd is key-value store, that kubernetes uses as store for all the configs. (Or most of k8s distributions, k8s is plugable so you can change it, but kubeadm definetly uses etcd)

#### Solution Hint

Restoring etcd quorum is no easy task as it seems, you have to backup data from your node, and than create new etcd cluster. I could not find any good guide how to do that with kubeadm, that's the reason this is not a perfect answers.

You cannot simple remove members, because that requires having a quorum, what you shoud be able to do, is create new etcd cluster, using the data from the old.

Kubeadm have a little bit of help here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#volume-snapshot

#### Long term notes:

If you have two failure domains, you will have to pick, which one is the more important one. There is no way, to be able to run anyone part without the other, it would create a logical problem. If any part of you cluster, could run on its own, there could be a situation of network partition between those two datacenters so they wouldn't see each other, but otherwise run without any problem. Both parts of the cluster would assume master and start doing changes. When the network came back up, you can not decide wich changes are the correct ones. That's the reason all consitent distributed data-stores requires majority of nodes.

Also etcd is not recommended to use accros data-centers, maybe try to look at https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed